# For a ServiceInstaller what event is triggered on Upgrade?

Tags: c#, .net

I have been relying on the ServiceInstaller::AfterInstall event to run code that is required before the service can run.  However, now I need to do certain config checks before upgrading.   AfterInstall does not run on upgrades.  Is there a way to trigger an event on Upgrade?

Comment: How are you upgrading the Windows Service?

Comment: It's a standard MSI installer.  We use a ServiceInstaller class for events.   If the previous version is still installed when the new installer is run, it runs does not trigger the AfterInstall event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is the second time you run the MSI installer, the Windows Service is actually not reinstalled and only the exe is updated.

How about moving your AfterInstall code to a different method and calling the code when the exe is executed with certain parameters such as "/first". This code will be only executed with that command line parameter and not executed in the OnStart event.

Then when you create the MSI, add a Custom action on post installation to execute your exe with the command line parameter.